# MS SQL Server 2019 export db from commandline

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I need to export data from my MS SQL Server 2019, but I need to do so from the command line.

How can I achieve this? What are the best practices for exporting schemas?

As per comments below, I wanted to just use the mdf file but was encouraged not to.

Comment: Using a command line interface. There are plenty out there to choose from.

Comment: As an aside, you don't export data "to" an MDF, that's the data file of the database itself. It's not a good medium to transmit the database in; even a backup file is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the bcp command line utility that allows for exporting data to flat files from tabular.
The utility is part of the sql server setup and is available on your system

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15